# Setting modem sleep

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I'm trying to run my wemos d1, in modem sleep mode, in order to reduce the power consumption, when I run my script I use the WiFi.forceSleepBegin(), and this instruction works because, the module disconnect from Wifi, in fact if I try to ping it, the module doesn't respond. The problem is that when I execute the WiFi.forceSleepWake(), the module don't wake up, and remain disconnected from wifi, now the ping doesn't work.
I suspect that the modem sleep is not set properly, how I can set it?

Comment: Do you have at least 100 ms delay between those commands?

Comment: yes, after the WiFi.forceSleepWake(), I inserted a 110 ms delay and I make a check with if(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)  Serial.println("Not connected!"), the result is that on the serial monitor appears the message, confirming that the WiFi.forceSleepWake() is not working. Do you know how I can set the sleep mode in the arduino IDE?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to re connect to WiFi on wake up as it won't re do it for you, remember you disconnected from the WiFi to get in modem sleep mode